# CSS element doesn't cover 100% of the page

Tags: html, css

First and foremost, this **IS** a university assignment, as basic as it might seem, I've been trying to solve this for the last 3 hours, and nothing seems to be working.

So I've got side navigation bar set to `height: 100;`
However, it ends close to the bottom of the page for no apparent reason. Resizing the window enough pushes the navigation bar past the footer, which leaves the footer hanging right below the last element on the page

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 850px)" href="css/style2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 450px)" href="css/style3.css" />
    <!-- <script src="js/main.js"></script> -->
    <title>CS15020: Web Development Tools</title>
</head>

<body>
<header class="text element-color">
    <h1>David’s assignment 2 for CS15020</h1>
</header>

<nav>
    <a href="">Email me</a><br />
    <a href="prac2.html">My CV (no CSS)</a><br />
    <a href="prac2_centered.html">My CV (with CSS)</a><br />
    <a href="..">Homepage</a><br />
    <a href="" target="_blank">My website</a><br />
    <br /> <!-- dirty way of making media queries work -->
    <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">Valid HTML5</a><br />
    <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">Valid CSS</a>
</nav>

<main>
<br />
Please enter your details below:
<form id="userDetails" action="/">
<p>
<input type="text" id="users_name" placeholder="Name" />
<br />
<select name="grade">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>

<input type="button" name="send" onclick="process()" value="Submit" />
</form>

<p id="out"></p>
<img src="images/web.jpg" alt="web image"></img>
<p id="dateModified"></p>

<script>
function process() {
        var txt = "";
        var hoursOut = "";
        var name = document.getElementById("users_name").value;

        switch(document.forms['userDetails'].grade.selectedIndex){
        case 0:
            txt="1/5 (20%); Wow you must really suck at life...";
            break;
        case 1:
            txt="2/5 (40%); Meh...";
            break;
        case 2: 
            txt="3/5 (60%); Well... at least you know something, right?";
            break;
        case 3:
            txt="4/5 (80%); It's getting good!";
            break;
        case 4:
            txt="5/5 (100%); Awesome bro, keep it goin'!";
            break;
        }

    var hours = (new Date()).getHours();

    if (hours >= 12 && hours < 18) {
    hoursOut = "afternoon";
    } else if (hours < 12 && hours >= 5) {
    hoursOut = "morning";
    } else if (hours >= 18 && hours <= 23) {
    hoursOut = "evening";
    } else hoursOut = "night";


    var finalOut = document.getElementById("out");
    finalOut.innerHTML = "Good " + hoursOut + ", " + name + "! You expected grade " + txt;
    }

    var mod = new Date(document.lastModified);
    var modFormatted = mod.toLocaleString();
    document.getElementById("dateModified").innerHTML = "Last modified: " + modFormatted;
</script>
</main>

<div id="footer" class="text element-color">
    CS15020 - WEB DEVELOPMENT TOOLS
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
main {
    margin-left: 15%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body
{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #F8E0E0;
}

.text {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.element-color {
    color: #818181;
}

header {
    background-color: #111;
    width: 100%;
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

nav {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 12%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #111;
    border-top: 2px solid #818181;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #818181;
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
}

nav a:hover{
    color: white;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#footer { 
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    color: #818181;

}
```

CSS #2:

```
main {
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body
{
    margin:0;
    background-color: #F8E0E0;
}

.text {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.element-color {
    color: #818181;
}

header {
    background-color: #111;
    width: 100%;
    /*border-bottom: 2px solid white;*/
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 100%;
}

nav {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 0%;
    width: 16%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #111;
    border-top: 2px solid #818181;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 85%;
    color: #818181;
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
}

nav a:hover{
    color: white;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#footer { 
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    color: #818181;

}
```

CSS #3:

```
main {
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 5%;
    padding-top: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body
{
    margin:0;
    background-color: #F8E0E0;
}

.text {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.element-color {
    color: #818181;
}

header {
    background-color: #111;
    /*border-bottom: 2px solid white;*/
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 100%;
}

nav {
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-top: 2px solid #818181;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 85%;
    /*color: #818181;*/
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
}

br { 
    display: none;
}

nav a:hover{
    color: white;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#footer { 
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    color: #818181;

}
```

CSS sheets #2 and #3 and purely just for media queries

UPDATE: You can actually see the whole thing [here](http://users.aber.ac.uk/dec21/cs15020); I have now changed the height to fixed.

Comment: can you create fiddle to show your problem ?

Comment: What is your goal? To have `main` take up the whole view?

Comment: No, I want to get the menu sidebar to not have a massive white space after it, or before it if setting it to `height: fixed;`
I updated the question with the link to the actual website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change  `nav's`  position from `absolute` to `fixed` in CSS (first one). It worked for me.

EDITED

```
 header {
    background-color: #111;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 12%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 42px;
    background-color: #111;
    border-top: 2px solid #818181;
}
```

Comment: It works, but then the header becomes detached from the nav, that's especially evident when scrolling.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. To fix that you can assign fixed position to the header and top margin (42px) to nav. So, you will have fixed header and nav but rest of the page will be scroll-able. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: That also works, but it covers the top part of content within `main`, adding margin to either `main` or `body` just adds a margin above the header.

Comment: Adding top padding to <code>main</code> will help :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved the scrollable content problem by **Flex**.

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
}

.nav {
  flex: 1;
  background: black;
}

.main {
  flex: 4;
}

main {
  margin-left: 15%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F8E0E0;
}

.text {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.element-color {
  color: #818181;
}

header {
  background-color: #111;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #818181;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: white;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #818181;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="text element-color">
    <h1>David’s assignment 2 for CS15020</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="nav">
      <nav>
        <a href="">Email me</a><br />
        <a href="prac2.html">My CV (no CSS)</a><br />
        <a href="prac2_centered.html">My CV (with CSS)</a><br />
        <a href="..">Homepage</a><br />
        <a href="" target="_blank">My website</a><br />
        <br />
        <!-- dirty way of making media queries work -->
        <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">Valid HTML5</a><br />
        <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">Valid CSS</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <main>
        <br /> Please enter your details below:
        <form id="userDetails" action="/">
          <p>
            <input type="text" id="users_name" placeholder="Name" />
            <br />
            <select name="grade">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>

            <input type="button" name="send" onclick="process()" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <p id="out"></p>
        <img src="images/web.jpg" alt="web image">
        <p id="dateModified"></p>

        <br /> Please enter your details below:
        <form id="userDetails" action="/">
          <p>
            <input type="text" id="users_name" placeholder="Name" />
            <br />
            <select name="grade">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>

            <input type="button" name="send" onclick="process()" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <p id="out"></p>
        <img src="images/web.jpg" alt="web image">
        <p id="dateModified"></p>

        <br /> Please enter your details below:
        <form id="userDetails" action="/">
          <p>
            <input type="text" id="users_name" placeholder="Name" />
            <br />
            <select name="grade">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>

            <input type="button" name="send" onclick="process()" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <p id="out"></p>
        <img src="images/web.jpg" alt="web image">
        <p id="dateModified"></p>

        <br /> Please enter your details below:
        <form id="userDetails" action="/">
          <p>
            <input type="text" id="users_name" placeholder="Name" />
            <br />
            <select name="grade">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>

            <input type="button" name="send" onclick="process()" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <p id="out"></p>
        <img src="images/web.jpg" alt="web image">
        <p id="dateModified"></p>

        <br /> Please enter your details below:
        <form id="userDetails" action="/">
          <p>
            <input type="text" id="users_name" placeholder="Name" />
            <br />
            <select name="grade">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>

            <input type="button" name="send" onclick="process()" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <p id="out"></p>
        <img src="images/web.jpg" alt="web image" />
        <p id="dateModified"></p>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer" class="text element-color">
    CS15020 - WEB DEVELOPMENT TOOLS
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It breaks if you add some scrollable content, see the link I added to the question

Comment: Check the edit. And to keep your navbar of fixed width. You can add `min-width` and `max-width` to your desirable `px` assigned to `.nav`

Answer (score 0):

A fixed position might work better if there's another element pushing it around, although this might not work well with your desired end product.

Compatibility is not as good, but you could try setting height to 100vh. This will set it to 100 1/100ths of the user's viewport which would be the whole screen.

Comment: Tried making it fixed, that works fine with the bottom, but detaches the header from the menu, so if you scroll, there's a white space the height of a header above the nav